# Javascript -HTML5 audio controls when song is selected

Tags: javascript, html

Hi this is currently my code to play a song according to which image is selected:

Javascript

```
function Start (audioFile)
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = audioFile;
    audie.play();
}

function Stop ()
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.pause();
}
```

HTML5

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="37" height="30" onclick="Start('EL.mp3')">
```

How is it that i could show the HTML 5 audio player with all the controls as soon as the button is selected ? I would like to just have one control bar and everytime the playbutton is clicked the bar appears and maybe display the song that is currently playing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i suggest using jquery for writing JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<audio controls id="myAudio" style="display:none">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Start (audioFile) 
{
    $("#myAudio").show();
    ...
}

function Stop ()
{
    $("#myAudio").hide();
    ...
}
```